# When the range of positiv operator is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space 
and
$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{+}:=\Big\{A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\;\;\langle Au,u\rangle\geq0,\;\forall\;u\in \mathcal{H}\Big\}.$

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^{+}$. Assume that $\mathcal{R}(A)=\mathcal{R}(A^{\frac{1}{2}})$, why we have $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is closed?? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T\geqslant 0$, we have $\mathrm{Ran}(T)^\perp = \mathrm{Ker}(T)$. Thus, $\mathrm{Ran}(T)$ is closed if and only if $\mathrm{Ker}(T)^\perp\subseteq \mathrm{Ran}(T)$. So pick $y\in \mathrm{Ker}(T)^\perp$. Since $\mathrm{Ran}(T)=\mathrm{Ran}(T^{1/2})$, we can pick $x\in \mathrm{Ker}(T)^\perp$ such that
$$
T^{1/2}T^{1/2} x = Tx = T^{1/2} y.
$$
But then $T^{1/2}(T^{1/2} x - y)=0$, i.e. $T^{1/2} x - y\in \mathrm{Ker}(T^{1/2})$. Thus, we have $y=T^{1/2}x\in\mathrm{Ran}(T^{1/2})=\mathrm{Ran}(T)$, assuming that we can show that $T^{1/2}x-y\in \mathrm{Ker}(T^{1/2})^\perp$. Since $T^{1/2}x\in \mathrm{Ran}(T^{1/2})\subseteq\mathrm{Ker}(T^{1/2})^\perp$, we must show that $y\in \mathrm{Ker}(T^{1/2})^\perp$.

> **Lemma:** $\mathrm{Ker}(T) = \mathrm{Ker}(T^{1/2})$.

**Proof:** If $T^{1/2}x=0$, then $Tx=T^{1/2}T^{1/2}x=0$. On the other hand, if $Tx=0$, then $\lVert T^{1/2}x \rVert^2=\langle x, Tx\rangle=0$, so $T^{1/2}x=0$.